# How to have an error but continue the script in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have this code in Python:

```
l = dict['link']
t = dict['title']        <<<<<<<<error here, there is no "title"
d = dict['description']
k = dict['keyword']
```

What if there is an error on line 2, but I want it to continue running the script and assign the other values?  Can I just "ignore" the errors?

EDIT: I know how to do a simple try, except. However, Oftentimes when there is an error on #2, it will shoot to the except, and then NOT continue the rest of the code.'

EDIT: I understand that there is a "get" method. However, I'd like a GENERAL way of doing it...I won't always be using dictionaries.

Comment: btw, `dict` isn't a good name - it shadows the built-in `dict()` function.

Comment: The general way is to use a `try`..`catch` for places you know an error might occur, so that you can handle it properly (such as defining a default value.) You can't just have it ignore an error and continue, because then the behavior of the code would be undefined (what should the value of `t` be?) Sounds like you're looking for an `On Error Resume Next` statement...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest option is to use [`.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
l = dict.get('link')
t = dict.get('title')
d = dict.get('description')
k = dict.get('keyword')
```

The `t` variable will then contain `None` (you can use `dict.get('title', '')` if you want an empty string, for example). Another option would be to catch the `KeyError` exception.

Answer (score 8):

```
t = dic.get('title')
```

won't produce the error. it's equivalent to:

```
try:
    t = dic['title']
except KeyError:
    t = None
```

and please don't shadow built-in, don't use `dict` for a variable name. use something else.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a way to consume exceptions and continue (though this is probably not a good idea) you could use a wrapper function such as:

```
def consume_exception(func, args, exception):
    try:
        return func(*args)
    except exception:
        return None
```

Or something like that.

Then call

```
l = consume_exception(dict.__getitem__, ['link'], KeyError)
t = consume_exception(dict.__getitem__, ['title'], KeyError)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your best bet is to use

```
l = dict.get('link', 'default')
t = dict.get('title', 'default')
```

etc.

Any values that weren't in the dictionary will be set to `'default'` (or whatever you choose). Of course, you'll have to deal with this later...

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of Try Catch and exception handling? You can readup on them [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)

However, you should shy away from causing errors on purpose, why do you have code that you know will fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try/except/finally; see the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)

However, the main question is; why are you assigning these to variables in the first place instead of accessing the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Use exceptions

```
try:
    l = dict['link']
    t = dict['title']  
    d = dict['description']
    k = dict['keyword']
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    print ('something')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the error for a specific KeyWord that you know might raise then I would suggest you the following:

```
try:
    l = dict['link']
    t = dict['title']        <<<<<<<<error here, there is no "title"
    d = dict['description']
    k = dict['keyword']
except KeyError as err:
    if 'title' in err.args:
        # Do what you like to handle this error
        pass 
    else:
        # if the error is not for the specific keyword then 
        # you can simple raise the error or do something else
        print(err)
```

This will efficiently handle this error and continue the script afterwards.